# How to use Wix in a Team Environment

Tags: .net, installation, wix

I created a Wix Install Project in our solution and prepared an installer for our project. The problem is that everyone in our team has to install Wix Toolset to load the wix setup project. I don't want anyone other than the ones responsible from the setup project to have to install wix toolset.

I tried the "unload project" solution but when the project is right clicked there is no unload option since the project gives an incompatible project error.

How do you use wix projects in you team environments?

Comment: The solutions that non-setup developers load need not have setup projects in them. (A solution includes zero or more projects. A project is a member of zero or more solutions. There is no restriction on the relative paths between projects and solutions.) But, yeah, what @Morten says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option could be authoring 2 `sln` files: one with `wixproj` and the other without it. Thus, a person responsible for installation program development uses the first one, others use the latter.

Answer (score 4):

If only part of the developers are able to develop WiX and maybe some other developers only being able to develop technology-X, then you might end up with small silos inside your team. Instead share knowledge by enabling access to all technologies for all team members. This will inspire and enable innovation.

Comment: Thank you for the good advice but I want to have the option of not installing another setup. There is already enough things to install as it is.

Comment: It's either this or remove the WiX projects from your solution and manage them separately.  Installing the tooling on all machines is a much better option IMO.

Answer (score 0):

If your error is occurring on the workstations where Wix Toolset isn't installed, I would have the developer *with* Wix unload his project and commit it, then reload the project to keep working on it.

Then, when the workstation without Wix updates from the repo, they wouldn't have the project loaded, and thus there should be no error.

That said, this doesn't seem like a clean solution. Is there some reason you can't have Wix installed on multiple workstations?

Comment: There is no reason they can't have Wix installed. But I don't want them to have to install it, just to develop code on some other parts of the solution.

Comment: Unloading a project stores this state information in the user setting files (.suo) This file is not stored in the repository since it contains user specific settings.